# Reading PPM image in C++ missing last pixel

Tags: c++, matrix, cin, ppm

I am attempting to read a PPM image from standard input with this code:

```
cin >> format;
cin >> ppm->width >> ppm->height >> ppm->colourMax;

for (int r = 0; r < ppm->height; r++) {
  ppm->pixels[r] = new Pixel[ppm->width];
  for (int c = 0; c < ppm->width; c++) {
    Pixel p = Pixel();
    cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p.r), sizeof(unsigned char));
    cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p.g), sizeof(unsigned char));
    cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p.b), sizeof(unsigned char));
    ppm->pixels[r][c] = p;
  }
}
```

However, when I output the PPM image unchanged, I am missing the very last pixel. Everything else seems to work perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: Did not check yet, but maybe you are missing the *first* pixel?

Comment: Which pixel coordinates are missing? Does this vary depending on the size of the input image? Have you tried more than one source image file?

Comment: When I compare the original file to my output, the original has 1 extra byte at the end.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can declare `Pixel& p = ppm->pixels[r][c]` and avoid creating a useless intermediate variable. Less copying that way.

Comment: A single byte is not enough for a pixel, as your code reads 3 per pixel. What is that extra byte and what is your system?

Comment: I have tried it with 2 different images, and same problem, there is 1 extra byte at the end, the byte is different for each image.

Comment: For 1 image the extra byte is 255 and the other is a 0

Comment: Hard to confirm without a real file, but it looks that your original files do have an extra byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PPM file format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) has for all its variant a single space character following the `colourMax` parameter:

> Each PPM image consists of the following:
>
> ...
>     5. A height, again in ASCII decimal.
>     6. Whitespace.
>     7. The maximum color value (Maxval), again in ASCII decimal. Must be less than 65536 and more than zero.
>      **8. A single whitespace character (usually a newline).**
>     ...

In your code, this extra whitespace is not extractacted from the stream because `read()` starts reading at the current position. And as you read an fixed number of chars, this extras space, causes your code to ignore the last char.

Solution:  just [`cin.ignore();`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) before starting your reading loops.